# Bulge bottom of a header

Tags: html, css

Just wondering if it's possible to do this in css:

http://puu.sh/2IS7n.png

I've created a simplified jfiddle version of my current testing site: http://jsfiddle.net/QhPQa/

HTML:

```
<header>
    Ight'sul
</header>
```

CSS:

```
body {

background: rgb(140,140,140);

}



header{
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 140px;
    color: black;
    background: rgb(201,201,201);

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 1px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         0px 1px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
```

Anyone know if it's possible, or if I should resort to an image again instead.

Comment: I really don't think so, your best option would be to create the image in photoshop and then just set the background to that image

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking of doing after spending so long searching around. This is my final resort to find if it's possible, else I will use an image.

Comment: what's the problem with using an image? Why waste time on finding a workaround? That's what images *are for*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use an image to achieve that effect, but where's the fun in that?? ;)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QhPQa/1/)

HTML

```
<h1 id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        lgth'sul
    </div>
</h1>
```

CSS

```
#inner{
    height: 200px;
    width: 120%;
    position: relative;
    left: -10%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 140px;
    color: black;
    background: rgb(201,201,201);
    border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 1px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         0px 1px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}

#outer {
    background-color: #3d3d3d;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}
```

**Explanation**

The idea is to have the `outer` div act as the backdrop for the curve and the `inner` div act as the curve.

Use [border-radius](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-radius) to curve the bottom of `#inner`

```
 border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%;
```

Set the width of `#inner` to a value greater than `100%` so that the curvature extends beyond the container and position it to ensure symmetry.

```
 width: 120%;
 position: relative;
 left: -10%; /*Move back half of excess width*/
```

Set `padding-bottom` on `#outer` and you're done.

Comment: Given that it's a header, I'd suggest using an `h1` (as in the original demo) as the 'outer,' and using a nested `div` (as you've done already) just for the 'inner,' element.